# Should the terms of service for a website match that for the company's service offering?

Tags: terms-of-use, saas

My SAAS company has a TOS for their service offering.  The TOS is provided to the customer when they sign up for service.  They want to add a TOS to their website like the TOS that shows up at the bottom of every website nowadays.

Does the TOS on the website needs to match the TOS of their service offering?  My initial thoughts are that they do not.  That the TOS for the website is for anyone who is using the website.  But the TOS for the service offering, is specifically for those using our service.  And that it could be the case that the SAAS company has multiple services each with their own TOS.

Comment: They are different. Just make sure the saas terms are approved before purchase.

Answer (score 3):

It might be a good idea to have consistency across your terms, otherwise people could be misled when searching for them.

If you don't decide to make them consistent you should at least advise in your public terms of service they are looking at are limited in scope and that other terms of service will take precedence if they are using your service. Also, depending on jurisdiction, the generic terms may be enforcable against you but not the visitor if they are not specifically brought to their attention.